# Marketing Cloud Custom Activity, contacts not moving

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created custom activity.

When added and configured in journey, after activating the journey I can see conatcts added to journey and execute method executed and all inAurguments values parsed in target app.

But then all contacts stay and wait and not moving further in the journey.
Looking into the journey history I can see they looks like failed with the message "Failed - Error during REST execution. Please check developer log for details".

Please if any one can help?

Thanks

Comment: As some one suggested in an other thread if remove the outArguments will solve this. When I remove the outArguments I am getting this error "Failed - ExactTarget.JourneyBuilder.Activities.RestActivityexecute: Error binding data bound member" and contacts stay in the journey and do not move further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing outArgument may solve your problem but that is not a solution.

Make sure you are passing values for your outArguments when you res.send in execute method.

e:g

if your outArgument(s)

```
`"outArguments": [{"CaseId":"number"}`
```

then in your execute response should be

```
res.send( 200, {"caseID": data.id} ); //return the new CaseID
```

Hope this helps.